# Check if the mouse is over an element?

Tags: jquery, animation

How to check if the mouse is still on an element after 3000 millisecond. I'm using `setTimeout()` but it triggers the eventlistener permanently.

thanks.

Comment: Can you please post code that you're using.

Comment: Tell us more, what are you trying to do?

Comment: clearTimeout(); wad what i needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tm;
$("a").hover(function(){
  tm = setTimeout(function(){alert("still hover");},3000);
},function(){
  clearTimeout(tm);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `mouseout` event together with `clearTimeout`